# Using .map in Promise.all

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

So, I have a few promises I need to run on init in my Express Server.

```
const dates = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
  dates.push(
    moment()
      .add(i, "days")
      .format("YYYY-MM-DD")
  );
}
const [cityName, weatherData, celestialData] = await Promise.all([
  axios.get(
    `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${latitude},${longitude}&key=${myKey}`
  ),
  axios.get(
    `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${myKey}/${latitude},${longitude}`
  ),
  dates.map(date => {
    axios.get(
      `https://api.ipgeolocation.io/astronomy?apiKey=${myKey}&lat=${latitude}&long=${longitude}&date=${date}`
    );
  })
]);
```

I need data from 8 different days so I thought by running a .map with the dates array I would get back another array with the resolved promise from each. This is not working as I expected.  How do I manage looped axios calls inside Promise.all?

Comment: `...dates.map()` - you need to spread the array that's returned into the main one.

Comment: You forgot to return the promises created in your `map` callback

Comment: and then use a rest parameter in the array destructuring: `const [cityName, weatherData, ...celestialData] = ...`

Comment: `Promise.all(dates.map(date => axios.get(...)))`

Comment: @Seblor Ahh yes, the return statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're really close. You want to

1. Spread out the array from `dates.map`
2. Capture the results in a rest element in your destructuring
3. Return the result from `axios` from the `map` callback

Roughly:

```
const [cityName, weatherData, ...celestialData] = await Promise.all([
// 2 −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^
  axios.get(
    `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${latitude},${longitude}&key=${myKey}`
  ),
  axios.get(
    `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${myKey}/${latitude},${longitude}`
  ),
  ...dates.map(date => {
//^^^−−−− 1
    return axios.get(
//−−^^^^^^ 3
      `https://api.ipgeolocation.io/astronomy?apiKey=${myKey}&lat=${latitude}&long=${longitude}&date=${date}`
    );
  })
]);
```

`celestialData` will be an array of the results for the dates.

If you like, you can use a concise arrow function for that third part:

```
  ...dates.map(date => axios.get(
    `https://api.ipgeolocation.io/astronomy?apiKey=${myKey}&lat=${latitude}&long=${longitude}&date=${date}`
  )
```

---

Side note: Your current way of creating the `dates` array is just fine, but if you wanted, you could use `Array.from`'s mapping ability:

```
const dates = Array.from(
  Array(9),
  (_, i) => moment().add(i, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD")
);
```

---

Since [Seblor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3670132/seblor) hasn't posted it as an answer, here's [their approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60656649/using-map-in-promise-all/60656751?noredirect=1#comment107315165_60656751) (which seems better to me since it avoids spreading out an array just to gather it back up again with a rest element in the destructuring):

```
const [cityName, weatherData, celestialData] = await Promise.all([
  axios.get(
    `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${latitude},${longitude}&key=${myKey}`
  ),
  axios.get(
    `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${myKey}/${latitude},${longitude}`
  ),
  Promise.all(dates.map(date => {
    return axios.get(
      `https://api.ipgeolocation.io/astronomy?apiKey=${myKey}&lat=${latitude}&long=${longitude}&date=${date}`
    );
  }))
]);
```

Comment: Would it also be possible to avoid doing your first and second point by replacing `...dates.map` with `Promise.all(dates.map => [...]` ?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - Cute. :-) But I think I'm just as happy with the unused param.

Comment: @Seblor - So `const [x, y, z] = await Promise.all([first, second, Promise.all(dates.map(...))]);`? Nice one! That sounds like a better solution to me than the above. Post an answer? :-)

Comment: Aggregation "by parts".